# Finding critical points

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $S\subset \Bbb{R^3}$ be the surface given by $x^2/4+y^2/9+z^2=1$. For $p_0=(1,0,0)$, define $f:S \to \Bbb{R} $ by $f(p)=|p-p_0|$. Then how can I find the critical points of $f$?

If I use 2 patches $(x,y) \to (x,y,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2/4-y^2/9})$, then $\tilde{f}(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2+1-x^2/4-y^2/9}$ and I should find $\tilde{f}_x=\tilde{f}_y=0$. But I think that this looks very messy computation and also I need to consider equator $z=0$ since it is not covered by the patches.

So I want to know that 1. is there better way to compute easily? 2. If I use the above patches, how should I treat the equator?

Comment: What have you done so far? You need to show your work and where you're stuck, otherwise this thread ends up getting closed by others.

Comment: @ChrisGerig I added some.

Comment: Is $|p-p_0|$ the distance between $p$ and $p_0$?

Comment: The easiest way to approach this is probably using Lagrange multipliers, since $S$ is given as a level set and $f$ extends easily to a smooth function on $\mathbb R^3$. (That is assuming that by $|\cdot|$ you mean the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb R^3$; if you mean distance measured on the surface then things will be a bit more difficult.)

Comment: $p-p_0\perp S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use patches; use Lagrange multipliers. You have one constraint $g=0$, where $g(x,y,z)=x^2/4+y^2/9+z^2-1$. At a critical point, the gradient of $f$ is a scalar multiple of the gradient of $g$. Since
$$\nabla f(x,y,z)= \frac{\langle x-1,y,z\rangle}{ \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
and
$$\nabla g(x,y,z) = \langle x/2, 2y/9, 2z\rangle $$
it follows that
$$\langle x-1,y,z\rangle = c \langle x/2, 2y/9, 2z\rangle \tag{1}$$
for some scalar $c$. (The ugly square root in $\nabla f$ is just a scalar, so it is subsumed in $c$). Equation (1) is three equations with four unknowns $x,y,z,c$. You also have the fourth equation, $g=0$. Some case-by-case analysis (is $y=0$? is $z=0$? etc) will be needed to find all solutions.